# how to download google appengine (uploaded)application files

Tags: google-app-engine

I need to download the application files that are deployed using command prompt into google appengine server.
if anybody know about this plz tell me!

thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I restore my source code that has been uploaded into Google AppEngine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479087/can-i-restore-my-source-code-that-has-been-uploaded-into-google-appengine)

Answer (score 19):

[SDK 1.4.0](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/0f90ef8dda3b8400) has this sort of feature (Python only):

> - The developer who uploaded an app version can download that version's
>     code   using the appcfg.py
>     download_app command. This feature can
>     be disabled on   a per application
>     basis in the admin console, under the
>     'Permissions' tab.   Once disabled,
>     code download for the application
>     CANNOT be re-enabled.

Note that although the 'download_app' command is only available in the Python SDK, it can be used to download Java applications from App Engine.  If you have a Java app that you want to download, just do:

1. Install Python (version 2.x only), if necessary.
2. Install App Engine 1.4.0 (or higher), Python version.
3. Run the python download_app command as described in the documentation, like `appcfg.py download_app -A <your app name> -V <version to download> <path to download to>`.
4. Your Java app will download.  Hooray!

Comment: Link to SDK release notes: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes

Comment: This is also available for Java apps now.  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_an_Application

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to download your code from App Engine, unless you included code to support it when you uploaded your app. You can download static files by simply fetching them, of course.

To achieve this, you need to use a source control system, such as SVN or Git, and store/retrieve your code from there - App Engine isn't intended to act as source control.

Comment: FWIW, the makefile I use to update to appengine first makes a zip of the source, which can be downloaded from the app (static file). The name of the archive includes the svn revision number, and the makefile refuses to upload if the current revision is mixed (on grounds that it would not necessarily be reproducible from the repository). This avoids needing any Python code to support the download.

Answer (score 3):

You can use appcfg.sh / appcfg.cmd in your GAE SDK, as pointed out in [this official guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_an_Application).

But notice that as of 2012-05-07, at least for the Windows version appcfg.cmd, the command's syntax is

```
appcfg -A yourappid -V yourversionnumber download_app c:\path\to\download\directory
```

Also notice that when you run this command and you get asked for your password and you happen to have activated Google's 2-step verification, you must not provide your Google password, but instead must provide an application-specific password (which you can generate [on this side](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens))

Comment: I did this to download my app, and then used the following code (after adjusting "WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml" to change the version#)

`appcfg.cmd update c:\path\to\download\directory`

but Im now getting an error when trying to run the app 

`Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/protobuf/InvalidProtocolBufferException`

Comment: I get the same problem...  did you ever find out what went wrong @johnvdenley ?

Comment: Above command only downloads the deployed application; I can not see any source file in WEB-INF\**.
Do i need to configure something in order to download the source code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `appcfg.py` with `download_data` option, see [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Downloading_Data_from_App_Engine%5D).

Comment: Not what the user is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in this post: http://www.labnol.org/software/download-appengine-files/19348/
App Engine 1.5.0 introduced the feature to download your source code.

The command is:

```
appcfg.py download_app –A MyAppName -V 1 c:\AppEngine\SourceCode
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download an application's source code by running appcfg.py with the download_app action in the Python SDK command-line tool:

```
    appcfg.py download_app -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> <output-dir>
```

Comment: The same command also for *[Php](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/tools/uploadinganapp)*, *[Go](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/uploadinganapp#Go_Downloading_source_code)* SDK.