# Download source code of deployed GAE application

Tags: google-app-engine

Can I download source code of already deployed app if I've lost it's source code on my hard drive? I've looked through application dashboard but couldn't find any option to check it out.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192128/how-to-download-google-appengine-uploadedapplication-files

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I restore my source code that has been uploaded into Google AppEngine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479087/can-i-restore-my-source-code-that-has-been-uploaded-into-google-appengine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SDK 1.4.0](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/0f90ef8dda3b8400) has this sort of feature (Python only):

> - The developer who uploaded an app version can download that version's
>     code   using the appcfg.py
>     download_app command. This feature can
>     be disabled on   a per application
>     basis in the admin console, under the
>     'Permissions' tab.   Once disabled,
>     code download for the application
>     CANNOT be re-enabled.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't, and there are no plans to offer such functionality. Sorry - consider investing in a VCS and backups next time.

Comment: Thank you. Fortunately, it was just a small personal project, for commercial projects CVS truly is a must.

Comment: I would recommend using a VCS for _any_ project. Git is easy and low-overhead.