# is there a way to download my application code from GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I accidently deleted my application code from my own machine, however it's running on Google App Engine (GAE), is there a way I could download it from there?

--

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192128/how-to-download-google-appengine-uploadedapplication-files

Comment: Also duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479087/can-i-restore-my-source-code-that-has-been-uploaded-into-google-appengine

Comment: Why aren't basic tools like source code control taught by institutions at supposedly 'teach' people how to write code? Did you either go to a dodgy university, or are you self taught?

Answer (score 2):

app engine actually recently added the ability for the developer who uploaded a given app version to download its source code:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_Source_Code

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this unless you have prepared your app ahead of time properly.  There is a chance the trick described by Nick in the duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479087/can-i-restore-my-source-code-that-has-been-uploaded-into-google-appengine) might work for you.  Otherwise, I would suggest using source control like git or svn.